# Should i use an SSL Certificate to protect information entered in a PHP form?

Tags: php, ssl, mail-form

I am developing a php form that collects personal information from a user. This information is not kept in a database, but will be sent to and email address. Would i need to do this over an https connection? If so please explain why or provide a link where i can obtain knowledge of this. How can hackers access this information if it is not kept online or stored in a data base?

Comment: Yes, you should use an SSL certificate. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

Comment: "How can hackers access this information" ... they can monitor the traffic of the site. If it is not transported over SSL, it is transported with cleartext, so everything passed in is visible to whomever is monitoring the traffic.

Comment: you say it's only being emailed, is that with the mail() function?  Even if they send you their data encrypted over ssl, you could still be emailing the cleartext out.

Comment: Very well understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say if the information is not sensitive, then you don't have to go for SSL certificate.

For example, if you are collecting the user's firstname, lastname, email address, and a message then you don't have to use SSL.

However, if you are collecting sensitive data like SSN, Bank account number, routing number, Credit Card numbers etc, then it is highly recommended that you use SSL.

Comment: The information is sensitive in this case, the form will be used as an electronic job application.